# Does microcausality plus the time-slice property imply local primitive causality?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, mathematical-physics, commutator, causality

In quantum field theory, observables are associated with regions of spacetime. One of the basic principles of relativistic quantum field theory is **microcausality**, which says that observables associated with spacelike-separated regions should commute with each other.

Another basic property of any quantum theory is the **time-slice property**, which implies that that operators representing observables at times $t>0$ can be expressed in terms of operators representing observables at times $t<0$, and conversely, for any time $t$.

In relativistic quantum field theory, the time-slice property is refined to what is sometimes called **local primitive causality**, which says that all observables localized a spacetime region $R$ can be expressed in terms of observables localized in the past (or future) light-cone of $R$.

Does microcausality combined with the time-slice property imply local primitive causality?

- I'm not asking for a watertight proof. I'd be happy with a compelling intuitive argument.
- The answer is obviously *no* in classical field theory, where all observables commute with each other. But I'm asking about *quantum* field theory, where most timelike-separated observables do not commute with each other.

Comment: No, I do not think so, you should assume a stronger hypothesis: every globally hyperbolic region of a spacetime must satisfy the time slice autonomously for the subalgebra of observables it carries. Actually this condition (which is part of the axioms of a general locally covariant theory) is the local primitive causality written into a differen fashion. The time slice actually states that the algebra of observables of the spacetime coincides with the algebra in an open neighborhood of any Cauchy surface.

Comment: @ValterMoretti It does seem clear that local primitive causality can be restated as the requirement that the time-slice property hold for every globally hyperbolic region (a natural axiom of in one approach to QFT), and I agree with your more-precise statement of the time-slice property. But if we fix a globally hyperbolic spacetime and assume the time-slice property only for Cauchy surfaces of that whole spacetime, is local primitive causality (time-slice for all globally hyperbolic regions) automatically implied?

Comment: It Is implied in specific models for instance based on hyperbolic evolution equations (free fields). I am not sure that it is automatically true in the general case without further requirements...

Comment: @ValterMoretti I guess that's exactly what I'm struggling with. I don't see how to enforce microcausality without assuming hyperbolic equations of motion. More graphically, I don't know what would prevent some noncommutativity from "leaking" outside the light-cone if the equations of motion are not hyperbolic. Maybe a simple counterexample would cure my lack of imagination. In any case, thank you for the feedback! You have more experience in this area than I do, and I'm willing to bet that you're right. My goal to understand *why* you're right. :)

Comment: That is my feeling, too, but I do not know a counterexample, since all examples that can be handled (and that I know!) use hyperbolic equations. These are not necessary however e.g. in Haag-Kastler axioms.  However the time slice axiom can be proved to be *false* when dealing with renormalization. Look for the most recent work by Buchholz and Fredenhagen about QFT in terms of $C^*$ (not only $*$) algebras.